# using #define for defining struct objects

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I came across this simple program somewhere

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char buffer[2];
struct globals {

  int value;
  char type;
  long tup;

};

#define G (*(struct globals*)&buffer)

int main ()
{
        G.value = 233;
        G.type = '*';
        G.tup = 1234123;

        printf("\nValue = %d\n",G.value);
        printf("\ntype = %c\n",G.type);
        printf("\ntup = %ld\n",G.tup);

        return 0;
}
```

It's compiling (using gcc) and executing well and I get the following output:

```
Value = 233
type = *
tup = 1234123
```

I am not sure how the #define G statement is working.
How G is defined as an object of type struct globals ?

Comment: Your `buffer` is too small, its length should be at least `sizeof(struct globals)`.

Comment: @user28264 There is a well written and thorough answer provided.  You should mark it as accepted if it answered your question or give more information on the problem/tell why it isn't sufficient.  Otherwise it will remain as unanswered since no answers have been accepted.

Answer (score 4):

First, this code has undefined behavior, because it re-interprets a two-byte array as a much larger `struct`. Therefore, it is writing past the end of the allocated space. You could make your program valid by using the size of the `struct` to declare the `buffer` array, like this:

```
struct globals {
    int value;
    char type;
    long tup;    
};
char buffer[sizeof(struct globals)];
```

The `#define` is working in its usual way - by providing textual substitutions of the token `G`, as if you ran a search-and-replace in your favorite text editor. Preprocessor, the first stage of the C compiler, finds every entry `G`, and replaces it with `(*(struct globals*)&buffer)`.

Once the preprocessor is done, the compiler sees this code:

```
int main ()
{
    (*(struct globals*)&buffer).value = 233;
    (*(struct globals*)&buffer).type = '*';
    (*(struct globals*)&buffer).tup = 1234123;

    printf("\nValue = %d\n",(*(struct globals*)&buffer).value);
    printf("\ntype = %c\n",(*(struct globals*)&buffer).type);
    printf("\ntup = %ld\n",(*(struct globals*)&buffer).tup);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The macro simply casts the address of the 2-character buffer `buf` into a pointer to the appropriate structure type, then de-references that to produce a struct-typed lvalue. That's why the dot (`.`) struct-access operator works on `G`.

No idea why anyone would do this. I would think it much cleaner to convert to/from the character array when *that* is needed (which is "never" in the example code, but presumably it's used somewhere in the larger original code base), or use a `union` to get rid of the macro.

```
union {
  struct {
   int value;
   /* ... */
  } s;
  char c[2];
} G;

G.s.value = 233;  /* and so on */
```

is both cleaner and clearer. Note that the `char` array is too small.